# get JSONArray data inside JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I need to get "examples" data that is an array inside of 'results'

[JSON FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kQy5.png)

and append it to a string. What would be the easiest way to do that?

this is how i would get "definitions"

```
private JSONObject queryResults;
...
...
    String finalResults = "";
    JSONArray results = queryResults.getJSONArray("results");
    for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
        JSONObject item = results.getJSONObject(i);
        finalResults += item.getString("definition") + " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this topic is related to Android application, the easiest way to get the mentioned value without using any additional libraries is to check if JSONObject inside the for-loop has attribute `definitions` and get the value as a String. 
You can go with it like this

```
String finalExamples = "";
JSONArray results = queryResults.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i=0; i < results.length(), i++) {
    JSONObject item = results.getJSONObject(i);
    if (item.has("examples")) {
        examples += item.getString("examples");
    }   
}
```

I assumed that you don't want to update your result String value if `examples` is not available in the JSONObject.
If you want to handle other cases, for example when "examples" is available in the object but is null or is set to empty String you can use other methods of JSONObject to check it. 
More info about working with JSONObjects you can find [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)

Comment: That is exactly the solution i expected, thank you very much!
I tried to approach the problem similarly, but did not knew about .has method. And in my case, there is no need to check for null objects

Comment: It's always a good idea to check the SDK/library docs when you are not sure which method is one that you need. Also I guess that you are working with the Android Studio which is based on IntelliJ IDEA, so after typing variable name with a dot it should display a list of available methods. This also can help.